# DatabaseError at/// column sample_waypoint.geometry does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, geometry, psql, geodjango

```
DatabaseError at /admin/sample/waypoint/
-
column sample_waypoint.geometry does not exist
-
LINE 1: ..."sample_waypoint"."id", "sample_waypoint"."name", "sample_wa...
```

---

Im trying to put a map into django application but I don't know why this error comes.

This is a table in psql.

```
CREATE TABLE "sample_waypoint" (

    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(32) NOT NULL
)

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('sample_waypoint', 'geometry', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
-
ALTER TABLE "sample_waypoint" ALTER "geometry" SET NOT NULL;
--
CREATE INDEX "sample_waypoint_geometry_id" ON "sample_waypoint" USING GIST ( "geometry" GIST_GEOMETRY_OPS );
-
```

I'm trying to add geometry column so map is drawn in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just from db view, if you want to add a new column, it should be 
`ADD` rather than `ALTER`.